# Replacing text on XWPFDocument table not working

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, xwpf

I'm trying to change the text of the run within the paragraph of a Cell, which contains a flag that I set just in order to change it.

The code bellow is an example of how I have tried to do this with one cell:

```
try {
            XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(docOut));
            int prevYear = getYear()-1;
            int nextYear = getYear()+1;
            XWPFTable t = getTablesList(docOut).get(0);
            XWPFTableCell r0c1 =t.getRow(0).getCell(1);
            System.out.println(r0c1.getParagraphs().get(0).getText());
            replaceTable(t,genMap("lastYearSlash", prevYear+"/"+getYear()));
            System.out.println(r0c1.getParagraphs().get(0).getText());
            doc.write(new FileOutputStream(docOut));
            System.out.println("Saved to: "+docOut.getPath());
            
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DocHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DocHelper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

When I print the value of the text of that cell, it actually shows how it changes, nevertheless, after writing to the document, nothing changes.

The function *genMap* just generates a hashmap which contains the place holder value(the flag I set), and the value that will replace it. Here is the function *replaceTable*:

```
for (XWPFTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
            for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
                for(XWPFParagraph p:cell.getParagraphs()){
                    List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
                    if (runs != null) {
                        for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                            String text = r.getText(0);
                            if (text != null && text.contains(m.get("a").toString())) {
                                text = text.replace(m.get("a").toString(), m.get("b").toString());
                                r.setText(text, 0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have used a very similar function to find and replace text within the document, but outside tables and it works perfectly (The function I'm talking about is exactly the same, but it reads all paragraphs of the document, instead of the cell).

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Not able to reproduce because of the lack of [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is `getTablesList(docOut)` doing? I suspect it gets tables from a file `docOut`? If so those tables will not related to your `XWPFDocument doc`. So you are changing a table which then not gets written via `doc.write`. Try `XWPFTable t = doc.getTables().get(0);` instead.

Comment: Oh my god this actually works!! I had been stuck there for days Alex, you don't know how much I appreciate it. Indeed getTablesList returned a list of xwpftables, thus, I really don't understand why that table didn't get written to

Comment: `XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(docOut))` gets a `XWPFDocument doc` form the file  `docOut`. This `Java` `object` `doc` contains the tables too but is now independent from the file `docOut`. Then your `XWPFTable t = getTablesList(docOut).get(0)` gets the first `XWPFTable t` again from the file `docOut`. This `Java` `object` `t` is totally independent from the `Java` `object` `doc`. Now you change `t`. Then you save `doc`.  But changes on `t` have no influence to `doc` because `t` and `doc are totally independent `Java` `objects`.